# Print Professor and Student Object using Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, inheritance

I'm a newbie in C++ (6 hours) and I have implemented this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/virtual-functions/copy-from/31972385) in C++ . I know this is a simple example but how can this be improved? Syntax wise or shortened code wise?

Here is the question from Hackerrank

> Create three classes *Person*, *Professor* and *Student*. The class
>   *Person* should have data members name and age. The classes *Professor* and *Student* should inherit from the class *Person*.
>
> The class *Professor* should have two data members: publications and
>   cur_{id}. There will be two member functions: *getdata* and *putdata*.
>   The function *getdata* should get the input from the user: the name,
>   age and publications of the professor. The function *putdata* should
>   print the name, age, publications and the cur_{id} of the professor.
>
> The class *Student* should have two data members: marks, which is an
>   array of size  and cur_{id}. It has two member functions: *getdata*
>   and *putdata*. The function *getdata* should get the input from the
>   user: the name, age, and the marks of the student in  subjects. The
>   function *putdata* should print the name, age, sum of the marks and
>   the cur_{id} of the student.
>
> For each object being created of the *Professor* or the *Student*
>   class, sequential id's should be assigned to them starting from \$1\$.
>
> Solve this problem using virtual functions, constructors and static
>   variables. You can create more data members if you want.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> There are two types of input. If the object being created is of the
>   Professor class, you will have to input the name, age and publications
>   of the professor.
>
> If the object is of the Student class, you will have to input the
>   name, age and the marks of the student in \$6\$ subjects.
>
> - \$ 1 <= len_{name} <=100 \$ where \$len_{name}\$ is the length of the    name
> - \$ 1<= age <= 80\$
> - \$ 1 <= publications <=1000 \$
> - \$ 0 <= marks<=100 \$, where marks are the marks of the student in    each subject
>
> **Output Format**
>
> There are two types of output depending on the object.
>
> If the object is of type Professor, print the space separated name,
>   age, publications and id on a new line.
>
> If the object is of the Student class, print the space separated name,
>   age, the sum of the marks in  subjects and id on a new line.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 4
> 1
> Walter 56 99
> 2
> Jesse 18 50 48 97 76 34 98
> 2
> Pinkman 22 10 12 0 18 45 50
> 1
> White 58 87
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> Walter 56 99 1
> Jesse 18 403 1
> Pinkman 22 135 2
> White 58 87 2
> ```

Here is my solution

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Person{
    public:
         string name;
    public:
         int age;
    virtual void getdata(){}
    virtual void putdata(){}
    virtual int  getID(){return 0;}
};

class Professor: public Person{

    int publications; 
    static int id;
    int getID(){return id;}
    public:
      void getdata () { 
          cin >> name;
          cin >> age;
          cin >> publications;
      }

    public:
        void putdata(){
             id++;
             cout << name + " "<< age << " "<<publications<<" "<<getID()<<"\n";
        }

};
int Professor::id = 0;

class Student: public Person{

    float marks[6];
    static int id;
    int getID(){return id;}
    public:
      void getdata () { 
          cin >> name;
          cin >> age;
          for(int i =0 ; i< 6; i++){
              cin >> marks[i];
          }
      }

      public:
        void putdata(){
             id++;
             float markSum = 0;
            for(int i =0 ; i < 6; i++){
                markSum += marks[i];
            }
            cout << name + " "<< age << " "<<markSum<<" "<<getID()<<"\n";
        }        
};
int Student::id = 0;
```

NB: The `main()` was already implemented and I had no access to change it but the classes were implemented by me.

```
int main(){

    int n, val;
    cin>>n; //The number of objects that is going to be created.
    Person *per[n];    
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){    
        cin>>val;
        if(val == 1){
            // If val is 1 current object is of type Professor
            per[i] = new Professor;    
        }
        else per[i] = new Student; // Else the current object is of type Student   
        per[i]->getdata(); // Get the data from the user.    
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        per[i]->putdata(); // Print the required output for each object.  

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> #include <cmath>
> #include <cstdio>
> #include <vector>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <algorithm>
> ```

Do you really need all of that? Especially mixing `<iostream>` and `<cstdio>` seems questionable. But I would reduce on that and use only

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Please, don't do that. It's considered bad practice for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and will only save you 5 characters every once in a while. Using 20 in the process to do so…

> ```
> class Person{
>     public:
>          string name;
>     public:
>          int age;
>     virtual void getdata(){}
>     virtual void putdata(){}
>     virtual int  getID(){return 0;}
> };
> ```

First off, the descriptions didn't ask for any method in this class. But I would keep two of them (the ones not dealing with IDs, that are not part of this class). Second, you don't need to put several visibility marker: once you write `public:`, everything that follows is public. Until an other visibility is used. Third, keep those attributes `protected`: they are your internals, you don't want every one to mess with them; at least not in ways you didn't allowed through your public interface. Lastly, since they don't have any code, I would turn the methods into [pure virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained) ones:

```
class Person{
    protected:
         std::string name;
         int age;

    public:
        virtual void getdata() = 0;
        virtual void putdata() = 0;
};
```

> ```
> class Professor: public Person{
>     int publications; 
>     static int id;
>     int getID(){return id;}
>     public:
>       void getdata () { 
>           cin >> name;
>           cin >> age;
>           cin >> publications;
>       }
>     public:
>         void putdata(){
>              id++;
>              cout << name + " "<< age << " "<<publications<<" "<<getID()<<"\n";
>         }
> };
> int Professor::id = 0;
> ```

Same here, you don't need `public` all over the code. Only once suffice. You are also using the `static int id` as the `cur_id` the challenge ask for. This is a mistake: if I create a `Professor` and output its informations using:

```
Professor p;
p.getdata();  // Inputting `Alice 42 42`
p.putdata();
p.putdata();
```

I will see printed:

```
Alice 42 42 1
Alice 42 42 2
```

Your code only works because there is only one `putdata` on each object in the right order. Any other usage would not work as intended.

You also appear to mix string concatenation and stream output to put a space between elements: get consistent. You can also chain the stream `operator >>` to condense the code a bit without loosing on readability:

```
class Professor: public Person {
    static int id;

    protected:
        int publications; 
        int current_id;

    public:
        void getdata () { 
            std::cin >> name >> age >> publication;
            current_id = ++id;
        }

        void putdata() {
             std::cout
                 << name << " " << age << " " << publications
                 << " " << current_id << "\n";
        }
};

int Professor::id = 0;
```

> ```
> class Student: public Person{
>     float marks[6];
>     static int id;
>     int getID(){return id;}
>     public:
>       void getdata () { 
>           cin >> name;
>           cin >> age;
>           for(int i =0 ; i< 6; i++){
>               cin >> marks[i];
>           }
>       }
>       public:
>         void putdata(){
>              id++;
>              float markSum = 0;
>             for(int i =0 ; i < 6; i++){
>                 markSum += marks[i];
>             }
>             cout << name + " "<< age << " "<<markSum<<" "<<getID()<<"\n";
>         }        
> };
> int Student::id = 0;
> ```

Appart from remarks I already said for `Professor`, I was surprised to see that you store the marks as `float`s. Nothing in the text nor in the example input lead me to such conclusion, I would expect `int`s here.

```
class Student: public Person {
    static int id;

    protected:
        int marks[6];
        int current_id;

    public:
        void getdata () { 
            std::cin >> name >> age;
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
                std::cin >> marks[i];
            }
            current_id = ++id;
        }

        void putdata() {
            int markSum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
                markSum += marks[i];
            }
            std::cout
                << name << " " << age << " "
                << markSum << " " << current_id << "\n";
        }        
};

int Student::id = 0;
```

---

One thing that I didn't enforce here but that you should get into the habit of using is qualifying attribute access using `this->` (such as `this->name` or `this->current_id`). It does not matter much here as the code is fairly simple but it can help a lot to understand things more easily when the code is more consequent.

Lastly, reading at the parameters ranges, you can consider using `unsigned int`s rather than `int`s.